# how to solve unable to create webviewcache directory in android

Tags: android

> In my application,whenever i go to
>   web view from my application,I got 
>   unable to create webviewcache
>   directory.How to solve this problem in
>   android

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**File permissions error**

`app-cache/com.android.browser` and `app-cache/com.android.browser/cache to 777`